# How to apply transformers and/or binding expressions to the data in a table?

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm displaying a dataset in a table. How can I modify the binding of one of the data cells to use a [transformer](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/properties#transformers) or maybe even a [binding expression](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/properties#binding_expressions)? In the property editor, it appears, I can only select bindings for individual cells from a list and cannot edit them in a text box.

Specifically, I need to display only a time part of a DateTime, in a *specific timezone*, and maybe (not sure yet) also make DateTimes look different if they are not for today but, say, for tomorrow.

Comment: Would be great if you accepted/commented, if an answer given to you worked or not.

Answer (score 2):

Formatting a date to show only time:

```
@datasource.item.DateTime#formatDate('HH:mm:ss') // format: 13:30:30
```

For the timezone question, can't you just go with the timezone the user has, which should be default for App Maker? Use this formatting to see the timezone in the date field:

```
@datasource.item.DateTime#formatDate('HH:mm:ss, zzzz') // format: 13:30:30, UTC+3
```

(More formatting options here: http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html)

For different styles for different dates I would use a binding expression for the date field styles:

```
getDateStyles(@widget)
```

In which getDateStyles would be something like:

```
function getDateStyles(widget) {
  var dateValue = widget.datasource.item.DateTime;

  var today = new Date();
  // setting the date to 00:00:00.00, don't know if there's a better way.
  today.setHours(0);
  today.setMinutes(0);
  today.setSeconds(0);
  today.setMilliseconds(0);

  var tomorrow = today.addDays(1);

  if (dateValue < tomorrow) {
    return ["MyStyleForPreviousDays"];
  }
  else {
    return ["MyStyleForFutureDays"];
  }

}
```

And I've created addDays method:

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  return date;
};
```

Hope this answers some of your questions, I probably didn't understand all of it right.

Comment: Everything you describe works well in a widget outside a table. If I'm trying to apply binding to a table cell, however, I don't get to edit it in a text box. A list to select from is all there is. That's the problem.